# How would SQL locks work if there is not indexing on sql server

Tags: sql-server

From my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021966/why-behaviour-of-transaction-isolation-level-is-different-in-tempdb-database-and), I am suspecting that locks work differently when there is no indexing on a table i.e. HEAP. I am searching for any answers but didn't get difference yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the differences in your previous question relates to Schema stability lock (R/W tran) vs. Intent shared lock.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> **Schema:** Used when an operation dependent on the schema of a table is
>   executing. The types of schema locks are: schema modification (Sch-M)
>   and schema stability (Sch-S).
>
> **Intent:** Used to establish a lock hierarchy. The types of intent locks
>   are: intent shared (IS), intent exclusive (IX), and shared with intent
>   exclusive (SIX).

The article also goes into further detail on both (when you scroll down the page).